Unresolved external symbol happend when compiling C++
im trying to make a super simple direct syscall. I have 2 file, 1 is the asm file and 1 is the main source file. The ASM look likes:
EXTERN wNtAllocateVirtualMemory: DWORD

.CODE
NtAllocateVirtualMemory proc
    mov r10, rcx
    mov eax, wNtAllocateVirtualMemory
    syscall
    ret
NtAllocateVirtualMemory endp

END

The source file:
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

DWORD wNtAllocateVirtualMemory;

typedef long NTSTATUS;
typedef NTSTATUS* PNTSTATUS;

extern "C" { NTSTATUS NtAllocateVirtualMemory(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress, ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, PSIZE_T RegionSize, ULONG AllocationType, ULONG Protect); }

int main() {
    PVOID allocBuffer = NULL;
    SIZE_T buffSize = 0x1000;

    HANDLE hNtdll = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll");
    if (hNtdll == NULL) {
        perror("Fail to get handle");
        return 0;
    }

    PVOID pNtAllocateVirtualMemory = GetProcAddress((HMODULE) hNtdll, "NtAllocateVirtualMemory");
    wNtAllocateVirtualMemory = *((char*)pNtAllocateVirtualMemory + 4);
    NtAllocateVirtualMemory((HANDLE)-1, (PVOID*)&allocBuffer, (ULONG_PTR)0, &buffSize, (ULONG)(MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
}

There is no error when i change the source type from c++ to c, but if the source type is c++, error happends.
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol wNtAllocateVirtualMemory referenced in function NtAllocateVirtualMemory  syscall_direct  <path>temp.obj  1       

Why is this happend and how can i fix it ?

name mangling. Use dumpbin to see the exact symbol name being generated. Making the variable extern "C" will get you close to the symbol you have now.

Since NtAllocateVirtualMemory is apparently not linked to the project or else why would you call GetProcAddress, then how can you call it? Shouldn't you rather call pNtAllocateVirtualMemory()?

@Lundin Thats the official way, but i want to call dirrectly from function NtAllocateVirtualMemory in asm file.

@Botje True, thanks man the variable should be extern "C" too

In the asm file linked to the project? If not then how could that possibly work?
